# Why I am getting index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0?

Tags: python, arrays, indexing

I'm trying to have my function go through the spread sheet inspect every other 3 columns and find the location (row number) of some values but it works partially. The code runs and returns some values but I get this error message between and it stops.

I'm using **`start=mm[0]`** to grab the first value from the array and **`end=mm[-1]`** to grab the last value.

```
def get_voltageStatus(r,t):
    for i in range (1,len(data[0]),3):
        m=np.where((data[1:,i]>=r) & (data[1:,i]<=t))
        mm_raws = []
        mm=m[0]
        start=mm[0]
        end=mm[-1]
        print(data[0,i])
        duration(start,end)
```

Error is:

> start=mm[0] IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size
>   0

Comment: No value in `data` is between `r` and `t`, so `m[0]` is empty.

Comment: r and t are being fed somewhere else when we call the function

Comment: if size is 0, then there is no element, and therefore 0 is an invalid index. In other words, the error message already covered this. Note that you are looking at m[0][0] and this uses globals so hard to test/reproduce.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this fixed the problem

```
def get_voltageStatus(r,t):
    all=[]
    for i in range (1,len(data[0]),3):
        m=np.where((data[1:,i]>=r) & (data[1:,i]<=t))
        print(i)
        mm_raws = []
        mm=m[0]
        if mm.any():
            start=mm[0]
            end=mm[-1]
            print(data[0,i])
            temp=duration(start,end)
            all.append([data[0,i],temp])
```